# Can there be a sentence after comma + that?

Tags: that

This is the sentence in question:

> To research the book, See traveled to a remote area of China that, she was told only one other foreigner ever to visit before her had ever visited.

I understand how to use parenthetical commas and I think this is an example of using those commas. I feel quite confident that there should be a comma before "only" so that it would read..."remote area of China that, she was told, only one other foreigner"

Edit: comma before only

Comment: You mean the comma should appear *before* "only".  And you are correct.

Comment: I'd say the larger parenthetical element *includes* the word ***that***, so if you want to include an (optional) comma, it should go after ***China***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm almost certain that's not correct

Comment: @bendl: I'm almost certain what we have here is one parenthetical element *(she was told)* nested inside another (everything after ***China***). So far as I'm concerned all the commas are optional (but ***if*** the inner one is demarcated it needs a *matched pair*). Consider the text if you remove optional ***she was told***. You could still treat what remains as another parenthetical element (for which only *one* comma is required, since it comes at the end of the sentence).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: After you remove *she was told*, what do you consider the outer parenthetical element? I don't mean to be argumentative, but I truly don't see it.

Comment: @bendl: How about I *explicitly* demarcate the optional clause with brackets? *She traveled to a remote area of China **(that she was told only one other foreigner had ever visited before her)***. The highlighted element (including the brackets, but not the final full stop) is syntactically optional, and could be removed in its entirety. I've corrected the awkward phrasing and removed the (even more optional) inner parenthetical element, but syntactically it's still the same construction.

Comment: Looks like a restrictive clause modifying the noun 'area', which does not draw commas. I see one reason for the original redundancy -- only one other foreigner ever to visit (in China) before her had ever visited (that remote area). I'd cut this right down to "only one other foreigner had ever visited."

Comment: You could also leave out *both* commas, so that "she was told ..." becomes an entire subordinate clause.

Answer (score 1):

Your correction is correct. The full sentence can be written:

*To research the book, See traveled to a remote area of China that, she was told, only one other foreigner ever to visit before her had ever visited.*

The end of the sentence is also redundant and the redundancy should be removed:

*To research the book, See traveled to a remote area of China that, she was told, only one other foreigner <strike>ever to visit</strike> before her had ever visited.*

The original sentence, without the comma after told, was incorrect. A good way to check yourself with parenthetical commas is to remove everything between the commas and check if the sentence still makes sense.

For example: *See traveled to a remote area of China that<strike>, she was told,</strike> only one other foreigner before her had ever visited.*

Becomes: *See traveled to a remote area of China that only one other foreigner before her had ever visited.*

Comment: Thank you for the sanity check. The book actually had the wrong answer.

Comment: Just to add to this excellent answer, it's better with two commas than none.  ie, *"To research the book, See traveled to a remote area of China that, she was told, only one other foreigner ever to visit before her had ever visited."* is better than *"To research the book, See traveled to a remote area of China that she was told only one other foreigner ever to visit before her had ever visited."*.  The commas help break the sentence up into easier-to-parse chunks, and they also represent the slight pauses that a speaker might insert when reading the sentence.